# Automated ssh-keygen without passphrase, how?

Tags: ssh, scripting

I would like to make an automated script that calls `ssh-keygen` and creates some pub/private keypairs that I will use later on. In principle everything works fine with....
 `ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /tmp/sshkey -q`
...except that it asks me for the passphrase that would encrypt the keys. This make -at present- the automation difficult.

I could provide a passphrase via the command line argument `-N thepassphrase`, so to keep the prompt from appearing.
Still I do not even desire to have the keys -*additionally secured by encryption*- and want the keypairs to be plaintext.

What is a (the best) solution to this problem?

The `-q` option which supposedly means "quiet/silent" does still not avoid the passphrase interaction. Also I have not found something like this
`ssh-keygen ... -q --no-passphrase`

Please do not start preaching about or lecture me to the
pro and cons of the "missing passphrase", I am aware of that.
In the interactive form (not as a script) the user can simply hit [ENTER] twice and the key will be saved as plaintext. This is what I want to achieve in a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

command1
command2
var=$(command3)

# this should not stop the script and ask for password
ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /tmp/sshkey -q
```

Answer (score 267):

This will prevent the passphrase prompt from appearing and set the key-pair to be stored in plaintext (which of course carries all the disadvantages and risks of that):

```
ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /tmp/sshkey -q -N ""
```

Using [Windows 10 built in SSH](https://www.howtogeek.com/336775/how-to-enable-and-use-windows-10s-built-in-ssh-commands/)

PowerShell:

```
ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f C:/temp/sshkey -q -N '""'
```

CMD:

```
ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f C:/temp/sshkey -q -N ""
```

Comment: This works. In case `/tmp/sshkey` already exists one gets an overwrite prompt, though. This can be prevented via redirecting/closing stdin - e.g. via adding `0>&-`.

Comment: So bad practice to generate a clear pair of keys in /tmp ;)

Comment: To make it not ask questions it's enough to specify the destination (`-f ~/.ssh/id_rsa`), and specify a passphrase (`-N ''`).

Comment: Is it possible to do this as another user?  When I try to do this it errors: `sudo -i -u $user_name ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /tmp/sshkey -q -N ""
option requires an argument -- N`

Comment: Thanks for the PowerShell example!

Comment: Powershell should be `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f "C:/temp/sshkey" -q -N '""'` (single quotes around a set of double quotes). While 2 sets of double quotes works in this specific case, it can cause issues when paired with additional arguments (such as empty comment/`-C` e.g.  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f "C:/temp/sshkey" -q -N '""' -C '""'` ).

Comment: This is a variation I came up with, in my case I needed to overwrite any previous ssh keys so mine looks like this `HOSTNAME=$(hostname) ; yes | ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$HOSTNAME" -f "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" -P "" && cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: @PotatoFarmer prefixing arguments with `--%` stops powershell of interpreting arguments as commands or expressions. [The stop-parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-5.1#the-stop-parsing-token)

Answer (score 61):

The simplest way I found to do what you want is this (example using default filename)

```
    < /dev/zero ssh-keygen -q -N ""
```

If the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file already exists, the command will exit without modifying anything.

If not, you get a brand new key, in that filename.

Either way, you haven't overwritten anything, and you know at the end you have a key.

Comment: confirmed: on lubuntu 14.04.2

Comment: If you really want it quiet, pipe the output to /dev/null: `cat /dev/zero | ssh-keygen -q -N "" > /dev/null`

Comment: On (admittedly antique) SLES 11 the above command fail to produce a key. `yes "" | ssh-keygen -N "" >&- 2>&-` works just fine however and does not output anything (whether or not a keyfile already exists), and does not overwrite a previously existing keyfile.

Comment: Verified on Ubuntu trusty (14.04)

Comment: Why do you cat /dev/zero?

Comment: @maxschlepzig That's how it answers "no" to the "do you want to overwrite?" prompt when the file already exists

Comment: @JoeHolloway I see - the `cat` is superfluous then, i.e. `< /dev/zero ssh-keygen -q -N ''` works the same.

Comment: edited to catch stray cat

Comment: Although not much better, `yes '' | ssh-keygen -N ''` looks slightly better (readable) to me.

Answer (score 27):

This worked for me:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa -q -P ""
```

The `-P` is the passphrase option, and `""` is the empty passphrase.

Comment: key_save_private: No such file or directory

Comment: The `-P <passphrase>` option is to provide the (old) passphrase.
https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen

Comment: works, but if the key already exist it ask for overwrite

Comment: `ssh-keygen -P ""` worked for me.

Comment: @GianfrancoP. Do you suggest using `-N <new_passphrase>` instead?

Answer (score 7):

You can use expect to send the "enter" for you

```
cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -x
XYZ=$(expect -c "
spawn ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /tmp/sshkey -q
expect \"Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):\"
send \"\r\"
expect \"Enter same passphrase again:\"
send \"\r\"
")
```

But be aware, that if the file /tmp/sshkey already exists it will fail because the output of the command will be different.

Comment: thank you for the contribution. the expect seems even a more versatile for problems in the same kind.... well those where scripting and user-interaction would conflict. I will be aware of the potential conflicht that /tmp/sshkey already exists and check for it prior to using your command.

Answer (score 3):

For another user, tested on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo -u username bash -c "ssh-keygen -f ~username/.ssh/id_rsa -N ''"
```

Comment: What is the relevance of doing it for another user? How does `ssh-keygen` depend on the user running it? I'm just trying to understand this better. Thanks.

Comment: Good point. One benefit is the rights are set correct by `ssh-keygen`. I have updated the answer to put the file straight in the right place. Now the command does everything in one go: no need to move files or change rights.

Answer (score 2):

I did a simple echo before ssh-keygen. So `su - <user> -c "echo |ssh-keygen -t rsa"`

This was tested on Redhat 6

Comment: I don't think this is the best answer around, but I think there isn't any reason to downvote either, guys.

Answer (score 2):

ssh key generation function which can be put into .bashrc or .bash_aliases

```bsh
# Make an ssh key if not exists, and copy ssh key to clipboard
# needs xclip to copy to system clipboard
ssh-key-now () {
    cat /dev/zero | ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "made with ssh-key-now" -q -N ""
    xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
    echo "ssh-key copied to clipboard"
}
```

Saves time when you've reinstalled OS and lost your ssh keys and have to set up gitlab/github again

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
sudo -u user ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' <<<''
```

It is intended to create the directory `~user/.ssh/`, so that the file `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys` can be created and updated to hold a public key for incoming ssh access.

A key pair is also generated but not needed for this purpose.

For example, one can prepare a boot-time init (kernel) parameter to preseed a live system for ssh access as follows:

```
ID=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)
pr1="sudo -u user ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' <<<''; echo '$ID' | sudo -u user tee -a ~user/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Include `"$pr1"` in the appropriate kernel parameter as a command which gets run automatically, as in `ocs_prerun1="$pr1"` for Clonezilla. Also verify that ssh service is enabled, as in `ocs_daemonon="ssh"`.